Apex Chart in angular: legend marker stroke color
I am using apex charts in my Angular project, and I want to add a border to the markers contained within the legend. I see that there is an attribute you can set called "stroke-width", but you are unable to set the "stroke-color", which is not an attribute found. The color appears to be defaulting to white.
I have tried using customHtml, but when I do, I find that now I can't pass the marker color.

The ApexCharts documentation doesn't suggest any explicit support for setting the stroke-color of markers in the legend. There is however potentially a way around it that doesn't involve customHTML.
The stroke color in the legend matches the value set for stroke-color on markers in the chart. If you don't want this stroke color to appear on the markers, you can set the strokeWidth to 0.
options = {
  ...
  markers: {
    size: 5,
    strokeColors: '#ff0000',
    strokeWidth: 0,
  },
  legend: {
    show: true,
    markers: {
      strokeWidth: 2,
    },
  },
  ...
}

Whether this approach works will depend on the wider chart styling.
